# date and time corresponds to time zero in python

Tags: python, time

is there a code determines what date and time corresponds to time zero using just the module time (in python)?

```
import time
x = time.time()
print(x)
```

Comment: maybe i have to do the calculation for how many seconds are per year and then present the result by year/month/day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Time 0' is *usually* the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch).

From the [`time` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html):

> The epoch is the point where the time starts. On January 1st of that year, at 0 hours, the “time since the epoch” is zero. For Unix, the epoch is 1970. To find out what the epoch is, look at gmtime(0).

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(0)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html):

> On January 1st of that year, at 0 hours, the “time since the epoch” is zero. For Unix, the epoch is 1970. To find out what the epoch is, look at `gmtime(0)`

Comment: thank you Colleen for the answer , and thanks for SilentGhost for editing